# Why does the LCD of a Spartan 3AN is not working?

Tags: initialization, vhdl, lcd

This is the subprogram for the LCD:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity VideoTest is
    port( LCD_E, LCD_RS, LCD_RW : OUT std_logic;
            LCD_DB : OUT std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            counter: IN integer;
            clk: IN std_logic);

end VideoTest;

architecture Behavioral of VideoTest is
    signal InitDone: std_logic :='0';
begin

InitAndSet: process (InitDone, counter, clk) is
    variable tencounter: integer :=0;
    variable tempcounter: integer :=0;
begin
    if (clk'event and clk='1') then
        if (InitDone = '0') then
        -- Enabling
            LCD_E <='1';

        -- Clear Screen
            LCD_RS<='0';
            LCD_RW<='0';
            LCD_DB(7 downto 1) <= "0000000";
            LCD_DB(0) <= '1';

        -- Return Cursor Home

            LCD_RS<='0';
            LCD_RW<='0';
            LCD_DB(7 downto 2) <= "000000";
            LCD_DB(1) <= '1';
            LCD_DB(0) <= '0';

        -- Setting incrementation and moving cursor;

            LCD_RS<='0';
            LCD_RW<='0';
            LCD_DB(7 downto 3) <= "00000";
            LCD_DB(2) <= '1';
            LCD_DB(1) <= '1';
            LCD_DB(0) <= '0';

        -- Display On, show cursor, blink cursor

            LCD_RS<='0';
            LCD_RW<='0';
            LCD_DB(7 downto 4) <= "0000";
            LCD_DB(3) <= '1';
            LCD_DB(2) <= '1';
            LCD_DB(1) <= '1';
            LCD_DB(0) <= '1';

        -- Function set

            LCD_RS<='0';
            LCD_RW<='0';
            LCD_DB(7 downto 6) <= "00";
            LCD_DB(5) <= '1';
            LCD_DB(4) <= '0';
            LCD_DB(3) <= '1';
            LCD_DB(2) <= '0';
            LCD_DB(1) <= '1';
            LCD_DB(0) <= '1';

        -- Set DD Adress to 0

            LCD_RS<='0';
            LCD_RW<='0';
            LCD_DB(7)<='1';
            LCD_DB(6 downto 0) <= "0000000";

            InitDone <= '0';
        end if;

        -- Setting the value (0 to 9 is equal to 00110000 to 00111001)
        if (InitDone = '1') then
            if (counter < 10) then
                LCD_RS<='1';
                LCD_RW<='0';
                case counter is
                    when 0 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110000";
                    when 1 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110001";
                    when 2 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110010";
                    when 3 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110011";
                    when 4 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110100";
                    when 5 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110101";
                    when 6 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110110";
                    when 7 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110111";
                    when 8 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00111000";
                    when 9 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00111001";
                    when others =>
                            LCD_DB <="00000000";
                end case;
            -- if counter is greater than 10, then put the number in two addresses.
            elsif (counter > 9) then

                LCD_DB <="00000000";
                tempcounter :=counter;
                for i in 0 to 8 loop
                    if tempcounter > 9 then
                        tempcounter := tempcounter - 10;
                    end if;
                end loop;
                tencounter := counter - tempcounter;

                case tencounter is
                    when 0 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110000";
                    when 1 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110001";
                    when 2 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110010";
                    when 3 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110011";
                    when 4 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110100";
                    when 5 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110101";
                    when 6 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110110";
                    when 7 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110111";
                    when 8 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00111000";
                    when 9 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00111001";
                    when others =>
                            LCD_DB <="00000000";
                end case;

                LCD_RS<='0';
                LCD_RW<='0';
                LCD_DB(7)<='1';
                LCD_DB(6 downto 1) <= "000000";
                LCD_DB(0) <='1';

                case tempcounter is
                    when 0 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110000";
                    when 1 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110001";
                    when 2 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110010";
                    when 3 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110011";
                    when 4 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110100";
                    when 5 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110101";
                    when 6 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110110";
                    when 7 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00110111";
                    when 8 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00111000";
                    when 9 =>
                            LCD_DB <="00111001";
                    when others =>
                            LCD_DB <="00000000";
                end case;

            end if;
        end if;
    end if;

end process InitAndSet;


end Behavioral;
```

Here are the User Constraints:

```
-- Constraints
NET "LCD_E" LOC = "AB4" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = SLOW ;
NET "LCD_RS" LOC = "Y14" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = SLOW ;
NET "LCD_RW" LOC = "W13" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = SLOW ;
NET "LCD_DB<7>" LOC = "Y15" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = SLOW ;
NET "LCD_DB<6>" LOC = "AB16" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = SLOW ;
NET "LCD_DB<5>" LOC = "Y16" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = SLOW ;
NET "LCD_DB<4>" LOC = "AA12" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = SLOW ;
NET "LCD_DB<3>" LOC = "AB12" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = SLOW ;
NET "LCD_DB<2>" LOC = "AB17" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = SLOW ;
NET "LCD_DB<1>" LOC = "AB18" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = SLOW ;
NET "LCD_DB<0>" LOC = "Y13" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = SLOW ;
```

As I've seen this program should activate the LCD Display since I've clear all of the old saved things in the memory, I've set the cursor to 0 location and then on specific number that increments (in the main project) it indicates the number on the screen. I've taken the constraints and the encoding directly from the User Manual for the Spartan 3AN - Beginner Kit.

Am I missing something? It acts as it is not powered or something.

Thanks in advance,
Bojan Matovski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (clk'event and clk='1') then
    if (InitDone = '0') then
    -- Enabling
        LCD_E <='1';

    -- Clear Screen
        LCD_RS<='0';
        LCD_RW<='0';
        LCD_DB(7 downto 1) <= "0000000";
        LCD_DB(0) <= '1';
        etc etc etc.....
```

One problem: You're missing a state machine in this first part.  Check out Case statements and how they work with state machines.  What will happen in the code you wrote is that LCD_RD, LCD_RW, etc will just be replaced with the LAST line of code that you have in that if statement.  Everything prior to that will be unused.

Another problem: InitDone never gets set to '1'.  Ever.

Yet another problem:

```
for i in 0 to 8 loop
    if tempcounter > 9 then
         tempcounter := tempcounter - 10;
    end if;
end loop;
```

This for loop doesn't behave the way you think it does.  You need to read about for loops in synthesizable code.  They do not behave like C for loops.

Comment: Yup, it shouldn't be "InitDone <= '0';", it should be "InitDone <= '1';". I have no idea how could I've done that!
For the rest of the comments:

1. I wish them to be replaced by the last line of code, but first I want to execute the first lines. If I put them in different processes, it gives the multiple drivers warning. How would a state machine help me here?

2. How come the loop doesn't works? I've been using loops in different projects in this manner all the time and they work perfectly. I just want to decrement tempcounter by 10 until it is less than 10, or until it reaches 8 iterations.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but you really need to pick up a book about writing synthesizable VHDL and read it thoroughly.  You wrote your code like a software programmer writes C code.  You need to write like a hardware programmer.  VHDL executes in parallel, C executes serially.  You can't drive the same signal from more than 1 process.

Comment: I write VHDL professionally.  Meaning it's my job.  Meaning I know what I'm talking about.  Your for loop won't do anything.  For loops in VHDL serve to replicate logic.  They cannot actually loop through lines of code the way C does.  So if I have this for loop:

for i in 0 to 8 loop

    temp[i] <= temp[i+1];

Comment: Then you are effectively writing this: temp(0)<=temp(1); temp(1)<=temp(2); etc.  This is a shift-right.  Not a loop.  Just because your code compiles does not mean that it will synthesize correctly on an FPGA.

Comment: It still didn't synthesize properly, so I simulated it, and it works perfectly in simulation. I'm starting to think that I'm stupid, or something :) Can you try to explain why my for loop doesn't works as expected more precisely? Why can't it calculate all of the for loops in one iteration? Why it must change the values on every clock signal? And why is that on simulation it is shown that it DOES decrements on every clock, when it's not logical, since the for is independently looping from the clock. It just needs the first rising edge as an approval to start. Or with a better example perhaps.

Comment: 1. tempcount starts at 85 and decreases by 10 on each clock cycle.  The for loop isn't doing anything.  2. Is reset active high or active low?  If it's active low you should call it RESET_N for clarity.  3. You are assigning int to the value of tempcount which is decreasing by 10, so it will start at 85 and the next clock it's 75, then 65, etc until it gets to 5, at which point the LED turns on.  By the way, nothing ever turns it off again, it's always going to be on.  I'm actually not sure what would happen to tempcount.  It just keeps decrementing forever!

Comment: I see... So my FOR is useless. If i take it off, nothing would change. Reset is active on high, but I will change it to be active on low, since It should've been that way from the start.

I am a bit confused about for loops now. I don't even have an idea how to use them now. What's their purpose?

Comment: You should not use for loops at all until you understand them. And even then they are used rarely. Use counters instead to achieve your goal.